# ValueError: bad file descriptor

Tags: python-3.x, windows, terminal, operating-system

I'm trying to write a script in which I need to get the terminal size in order to adjust the output text width appropriately. I use this lines:

```
import os
x = os.get_terminal_size().lines
```

which results in getting this error:

```
ValueError: bad file descriptor
```

What's wrong with the code?

Comment: Have you read the function's doc string and the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.get_terminal_size)?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import sys
import os
try:
    cols,rows = os.get_terminal_size(0)
except OSError:
    cols,rows = os.get_terminal_size(1)

sys.stdout.write('cols:{} \n rows:{} \n'.format(cols,rows))
```

Comment: It results in this error: OSError: handle cannot be retrieved

Comment: are you running on terminal as I also run on pycharm it gave me this same error once i ran on terminal it worked

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [page](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/79021/os.get_terminal_size) you can find multiple example with error handling